# What ist the rank of vector system in the following vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I had some difficulties with this quite difficult problem.

The vector space is $\Bbb Z_{2}^n$, we have

$(1,1,0,\dots,0)$, $(0,1,1,0,\dots,0)$, $\dots$, $(0,\dots,0,1,1)$, $(1,0,\dots,1)$.

What is the rank of this vector space?

Thank you very much for your help, best wishes,

Tom

Comment: What are your own thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I still don't know how can I write at this website mathematical expressions. I'm starting now to read articels about latex. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1):

Assume there is a linear combination of the first $n-1$ of these vectors that is equal to $0$. Since these are vectors over $\Bbb Z_2$, the coefficients are either $1$ or $0$. We have
$$
a_1(1, 1, 0,\ldots,0) + a_2(0,1,1,0,\ldots,0) + \cdots +a_{n-1}(0, \ldots,0,1,1) = (0,0,\ldots,0)
$$
Since the first vector is the only one that has anything in the first coordinate, we must have $a_1 = 0$. But then, the second vector is the only one that has any contribution to the second coordinate, so $a_2$ also has to be $0$. And so on. Therefore there is no non-trivial linear combination of the first $n-1$ of these vectors that equals the zero vector, and your set of vectors has rank at least $n-1$.

Does it have rank $n$? What is the sum of *all* the $n$ vectors?